Expert Indicator (EA) not returning proper signal value
I am developing a simple Expert Indicator (EA) to analyze Forex chart and need assistance with the indicator signals.  The code compiled without errors, but once initialized and tsignal is defaulted to the Max allowed double value of 1.79xxxxx
Please help to determine why it is not returning the correct signal values.
// Include the necessary MQL5 header files
#include <Trade\Trade.mqh>
#include <Indicators\Indicators.mqh>

// Create instances of the indicators and the trade class

CiBullsPower bullsPower;
CiRSI rsi;
CTrade trade;

double myBullsValue = 0;
double myRsiValue = 0;

void OnTick()
{

    bullsPower.Create(_Symbol, _Period, 14);
    myRsiValue = rsi.Create(_Symbol, _Period, 14, PRICE_CLOSE);
    
    myBullsValue = bullsPower.Main(0);
    myRsiValue = rsi.Main(0); 
    
    Comment(myBullsValue, "\n", myRsiValue, "\n");

    // Check for buy signal
    if (myBullsValue > 0 && myRsiValue > 30 && myRsiValue < 70)
    {
        // Place a buy order
        trade.Buy(1, _Symbol);
    }

    // Check for sell signal
    else if (myBullsValue < 0 && myRsiValue > 70)
    {
        // Place a sell order
        trade.Sell(1, _Symbol);
    }
}

